# Object state modification during thread execution

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I'm working on a little game (bomberman), using javafx. Basically, I have players which can plant bomb. The bomb has a duration (1500ms before explosion, for example).

So, when my player plant a bomb, I start a thread in the bomb, using a Thread.sleep(ms), and right after I notify the player that the bomb has exploded.

Thing is, my player can drop his bomb then move... But when the bomb explodes, it notify the instance of the player with the coordinate when the bomb was planted...

For example, if my player is in [2;2], plant a bomb, then move to [2;4], then the bomb explodes, my player goes back to [2;2]...

Anyone knows how could I actualize the instance of player my bomb is pointing to ... ?

Here's a sample of code :

```
public class Player{
    public void putBomb(){
        listBomb.add(new Bomb(this));
    }

    public void refresh(){
        System.out.println(xCoordinate+" "+yCoordinate);
    }

}

public class Bomb{
    public Bomb(Player p){
        observer=p;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                    notify();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void sendNotification(){
        observer.refresh();
    }

}
```

Comment: notify is a final native method in Object class, you can't declare it in your classes...

Comment: about your question - you can declare refresh as synchronized, that will fix your visibility problems

Comment: Actually the method is not called "notify", I just simplified it. Using synchronized doesn't change anything unfortunatly.

Comment: if I understood the problem correctly, when Bomb sleeps for 1.5 seconds and calls methods on Player object, it "sees" old coordinates. You should synchronize access to coordinates - declare all methods that read/write them as synchronized or make them AtomicInteger, for example

Comment: Making sendNotification method synchronized didn't help most likely because coordinate update method in Player class is not synchronized

Comment: Starting a thread that way---using an anonymous inner class inside a constructor---generally is a Bad Idea.  It won't bite you in this case because your `Bomb` class is stateless, but if `Bomb` had instance variables, the code in your thread's run() method would have a good chance of seeing the new `Bomb` instance in a partially initialized or uninitialized state.  Google for "leaking this in constructor."

Answer (score 1):

As your question is JavaFX specific, the recommendations on how to do this vary from a non-GUI Java program (because JavaFX has in-built concurrency assistance and a single-threaded application programming model).

You don't need another thread, you can use a [PauseTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html).

```
public class Bomb{
    public Bomb(final Player player){
        PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1.5));
        pause.setOnFinished(event -> player.refresh());
        pause.play();
    }
);
```

If for some reason you didn't wish to use a transition and you want to use your own threading, then you should look use [JavaFX concurrency utilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) such as [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).

If you didn't want to use a Task, then you can still create your own thread or runnable, but ensure that any callbacks are made using [Platform.runLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-).  For example:

```
public class Bomb{
    public Bomb(final Player player){
        new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                    Platform.runLater(() -> player.refresh());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Of the different approaches, I recommend the PauseTransition over the others as then you don't need to deal with concurrency details such as threading, which are easy to get wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your run method calls `[this.]notify()` without being `synchronized` on `this`.  I would expect it to always throw an `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

Also, it's almost always a mistake to call `notify()` without also setting some variable that other threads can examine.  The problem with `notify()` is that it *does not do anything at all* unless some other thread happens to be in a `wait()` call for the same object.  Without proper synchronization, you have no way to guarantee that that will be true.

There's only one right way to use `wait()` and `notify()`, and that's in a design pattern that Oracle calls a *guarded block*.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html